# ContentProvider for SMS in 4.4 (Kitkat)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to access the content provider for sms in Android version 4.4 onwards. I know about the following way

Uri sms = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

This doesn't seem to work for 4.4. Can anyone help and tell me the right path?

Comment: look at my answer Ekta, I think it should be useful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code Ekta:

```
Cursor c = cr.query(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, // Official CONTENT_URI from docs
                      new String[] { Telephony.Sms.Inbox.BODY }, // Select body text
                      null,
                      null,
                      Telephony.Sms.Inbox.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER // Default sort order);
```

Comment: cr is the content resolver? Also it says Telephony cannot be resolved to a variable. It doesn't even suggest an import.

Comment: just check is your application are belongs to api level 19?

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I'm updating it, then I'll test your code. Also can you tell me a way of pushing values into this db?

Comment: hmmm yup grt, newbie in andriod?

Comment: Nope. It takes time to download and update. Will let you know.

Comment: hmmmm ok let me knw...frm where r u?

Comment: Yes. It did the job that it talks about sadly that was not what I was looking for. Anyways Thanks a lot. I'll accept the answer. :)

Comment: Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI provides illegal argument exception Unknown URL while deleting messages from inbox. Any idea how it can be resolved?

Comment: try {
    int count = mContext.getContentResolver().delete(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI,
      "thread_id=?",
      new String[] { String.valueOf(threadId) });
    Log.e("", "in if block: " + threadId + "  " + count);
    toastMsg = count + " messages deleted";
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("", "in exception block: " + ex.getMessage());
    toastMsg = ex.getMessage();
   }
  } 

I have used this code block.

Comment: @seema means you want to delete the messages from inbox??

Comment: yes, I have to delete sms from inbox. My app is default sms app.

Comment: Also, i am able to read using URI content://sms, but not able to delete using this URI.

Comment: @seema okay, let me check it out.

Comment: @seema kitkat not allowed you to delete messages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988574/delete-sms-from-android-on-4-4-4-affected-rows-0zero-after-deleted
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168336/unable-to-delete-sms-programmatically

Comment: I have done this in lolipop 5.0.1 successfully with Uri content://sms... Then how come it is not possible in kitkat?

Comment: I have made my app is default sms app, and as far as i know, default sms app can do so.

Comment: @seema not sure I have also read it, but I think some devices are not supporting, try with some other device.

Comment: I checked in same device model (samsung S4).. one with 5.0.2 and second with 4.4.2. It worked in 5.0.2 but not in 4.4.2. So it is not issue with vendors or devices.