# Unable to delete SMS programmatically

Tags: android, sms

I have tried variations on deleting all or some messages from the SMS, including but not limited to thread id, id, where clause, etc.
Android manifest reflects read and write permissions.
I tried with variations on the SMS content, from inbox etc.
Nothing seems to delete the record.

Here is the last iteration:

```
    Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null, null,null);
    try {
          while (c.moveToNext()) {
             int Id = c.getInt(0);
             String pid = c.getString(0);
            // String uri = "content://sms/conversations/" + threadId;
             String strUriAll = "content://sms/" + pid;//SMS_ALL
             Log.d("URI is ", strUriAll);
             getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(strUriAll), null, null);
          //   getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(strUriAll), null, null);
          }

        }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e(this.toString(),"Error deleting sms",e);
        }finally {
          c.close();
        }
```

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: No, what version of Android is the device/emulator you are using

Comment: 4.4.2 api 19, also ran on physical device Galaxy S5

Answer (score 2):

Android 4.4 Kitkat introduced [changes in SMS handling](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) where now only the default SMS app is allowed write access to the SMS database - all other apps silently fail when attempting to write.

Comment: Thank you!  I updated the manifest, re-ran the app, and it delete everything accordingly.